# creating hive table using gcloud dataproc not working for unicode delimiter

Tags: java, hadoop, unicode, hive, google-cloud-dataproc

I need to create a hive table on a unicode delimited file(unicode charcter - ."\uFFFD", replacement character)

To do this we are submitting hive jobs to cluster.
Tried with Lazy simple serde using ROW FORMAT Delimited -

> gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster  --region
>  --execute "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hiveuni_test_01(codes
> string,telephone_num string,finding_name string,given_name
> string,alt_finding_name string,house_num string,street_name
> string,locality string,state string,reserved string,zip_code
> string,directive_text string,special_listing_text string,id
> string,latitude string,longitude string,rboc_sent_date string)  ROW
> FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\uFFFD' LINES TERMINATED BY
> '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION
> 'gs://hive-idaas-dev-warehouse/datasets/unicode_file';"

But this does not create the table correctly , entire row is put to the first column only.

We are using cloud SQL mysql server as hive metastore , checked that mysql has utf8 encoding also.

Tried with multidelimitserde -

> gcloud dataproc jobs submit hive --cluster
> dev-sm-35cb3516-ed82-4ec2-bf0d-89bd7e0e60f0 --region us-central1
> --jars gs://hive-idaas-dev-warehouse/hive-jar/hive-contrib-0.14.0.jar --execute "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hiveuni_test_05 (codes string,telephone_num string,finding_name string,given_name
> string,alt_finding_name string,house_num string,street_name
> string,locality string,state string,reserved string,zip_code
> string,directive_text string,special_listing_text string,id
> string,latitude string,longitude string,rboc_sent_date string)  ROW
> FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'  WITH
> SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim'='\uFFFD') STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
> 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT
> 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'  LOCATION
> 'gs://hive-idaas-dev-warehouse/datasets/unicode_file';"

This gives an exception - `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe not found`

I have put an initialization script during start of the cluster which will place the `hive-contrib-0.14.0.jar` containing the class `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe` in `/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/`. I see that jar is placed in the folder by doing ssh to the cluster.

Is there a way to read unicode characters by hive client while creating table or why do I still get an error classNotFound even after placing the jar in hadoop lib directory?

Answer (score 2):

`hive-contrib-0.14.0` does not have `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe`. Instead the full qualified class name is `org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe`. Notice the extra `contrib` there.

So change your query to use the correct fully qualified class name and see if it solves the issue. You probably don't have to explicitly add a hive-contrib jar. It should be already under `/usr/lib/hive/lib`.

[HIVE-20020](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-20020) and [HIVE-20619](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-20619) were done on Hive 4.0, and since you are using Dataproc, it shouldn't apply since Dataproc does not have Hive 4.0 yet.

Comment: Thanks .. After changing the class full name, it does not give Class Not found exception. But that does not solve the actual issue, hive table created has the full row in first column only , that unicode delimiter is somehow not recognized. any way this could be handled while creating hive tables through hive jobs only?